# create-react-app running issue even after just created it

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

```
*npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! github@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the github@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:*
```

or sometimes I am different kind of errors just after creating the app. which means no modifications to the default automatic generated project.

Answer (score 0):

and I managed to solved it.

the issue seems to be with my Yarn. incomplete uninstall or something like that. can't solve it by just reinstalling Yarn or uninstall it again. because of that, NPM create-react-app also create bugs, which IDK how.

but the solution is amazing, I just created the project in a different folder. trust me I'm not lying , different location do works in NPM. so I believe I need to format my computer to solve this 100%.

The cause maybe due to I have installed create-react-app via NPM globally and tries to install Yarn create-react-app.
anyway, by using a different folder location, my issue was fixed completely.